# How to set value from different table columns?

Tags: linq, lambda

I have 2 tables.

First table's schema:

- UserId: 11,  ReportId=1400
- UserId: 25,  ReportId=1510
- UserId: 30,  ReportId=1518
- UserId: 41,  ReportId=1550
- UserId: 50,  ReportId=1590

Second table's schema:

- UserId: 50,  ReportId=1400, DeptId=10
- UserId: 80,  ReportId=1510, DeptId=10
- UserId: 20,  ReportId=1518, DeptId=10
- UserId: 41,  ReportId=1550, DeptId=10
- UserId: 50,  ReportId=1590, DeptId=10
- UserId: 60,  ReportId=1525, DeptId=10
- UserId: 90,  ReportId=1526, DeptId=10
- UserId: 50,  ReportId=1410, DeptId=10
- UserId: 50,  ReportId=1489, DeptId=10
- UserId: 50,  ReportId=1327, DeptId=10

I need to change first table's UserId to second table's UserId where ReportId's are same.

I mean:

- UserId: **50**,  ReportId=1400
- UserId: **80**,  ReportId=1510
- UserId: **20**,  ReportId=1518
- UserId: **41**,  ReportId=1550
- UserId: **50**,  ReportId=1590

```
List<FirstTable> tableFirst = new List<FirsTable>();
tableFirst = FirstTableBL.GetAll();

List<SecondTable> tableSecond= new List<SecondTable>();
tableSecond= SecondTableBL.GetAll();

for (int i = 0; i < tableSecond.Count(); i++)
{
    tableSecond[i].UserId= tableFirst.FirstOrDefault(k => k.ReportId== tableSecond[i].ReportId).UserId;
}
```

But I get a Null definition error because tableSecond does not have all values of tableFirst.

What's the correct linq expression for this situation?

Comment: Wha do you want to assign if there is no value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` will return null if it doesn't find anything. You should put in a null check in your code and then continue:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tableSecond.Count(); i++)
{
  var fromTableFirst = tableFirst.FirstOrDefault(k => k.ReportId == tableSecond[i].ReportId)

  if(fromTableFirst != null)
      tableSecond[i].UserId = fromTableFirst.UserId;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way, using `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
tableSecond[i].UserId= tableFirst
    .Where(k => k.ReportId== tableSecond[i].ReportId)
    .Select(k => k.UserId)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(new Nullable<int>())  // replace as desired
    .First();
```

Comment: I don't think that OP wants the `UserId` to be changed if there's no match. Hence "I need to change first table's UserId to second table's UserId where ReportId's are same."

Comment: @IronMan84: perhaps, however, then our answers complement each other perfectly ;)